Need to show previous values where there has been a change in Rate
I need to produce a report showing where there has been a change in rate/funding values and what the previous rate/value was. I am using SQL Server Management Studio 19.3 - SQL Server 2019.
I have something like the following. I have never used the lag command before, am not sure if it is best in this case.
Basically I want to extract any entries in ci_periodicBillings (including the pb.RATE and pb.RESTYPE - connected to fm.fundingName)  where there has been any updates (date created and/or last updated) in a specific month and to show the previous values of the pb.RATE or fm.funding name by client.
SELECT 
    f.name as Home,
    c.surname,
    c.forename,
    c.resID,
    CAST(c.ADMISSION AS DATE) AS Admission_Date,
    CAST(c.leaveDate AS DATE) AS Leave_Date,
    CAST(BILLSTART AS DATE) AS BILLSTART, 
    CAST(ENDBILL AS DATE) AS ENDBILL,
    pb.dateCreated,
    pb.lastUpdated,
    pb.RATE AS Latest_Rate,
    LAG(RATE) OVER (PARTITION BY PB.CLIENT ORDER BY pb.BILLSTART DESC) AS Previous_Rate,
    fm.fundingName AS Latest_Billing_Funding,
    LAG(fm.fundingName) OVER (PARTITION BY PB.CLIENT ORDER BY pb.BILLSTART desc) AS Previous_Billing_Funding
FROM 
    ci_periodicBillings pb 
INNER JOIN 
    cs_clients c ON pb.client = c.guid
INNER JOIN 
    cs_facilities f ON c.facility = f.guid 
INNER JOIN 
    cs_fundingMethods fm ON pb.RESTYPE = fm.fundingID
WHERE
    ((pb.dateCreated >= '2024-09-01' AND pb.dateCreated <= '2024-09-30') OR
     (pb.lastUpdated >= '2024-09-01' AND pb.lastUpdated <= '2024-09-30'))
ORDER BY 
    f.name, c.surname, c.forename, pb.BILLSTART DESC;

Is there a better way I can get this information apart from using the LAG command please? I am currently getting false negative values from the previous rate column.
Sample data



Client
Rate
Funding
Last Updated




7F7CEE3C
£1570
Private
09/09/24


4A6BBC12
£1870
Private
01/01/24


7F7CEE3C
£1470
Local Authority
07/09/24


4A6BBC12
£1570
Private
01/01/24



From the above, I would only want to see the data for client 7F7CEE3C to show that the rate has changed to £1570, the previous rate was £1470 and that the funding is now Private with the previous funding Local Authority. The client 4A6BBC12 should not be included as the last updated date is out of the required date range of September 2024
Hope that makes sense.

Please provide example data and add a SQL Server tag

The problem you describe seems ideal for LAG. There is no better strategy.

I am getting false negative values from the previous rate columns with the current lag command though?

I have some ideas but I cannot test them without some example data.

Just edited in an example, thanks in advance for any ideas please.

Thanks for the data but we need example records for these tables: ci_periodicBillings, cs_clients, cs_facilities, cs_fundingMethods

What is a false positive? Is BILLSTART a date or a VARCHAR? You order by BILLSTART DESC, but maybe it won't be correct when it comes to strings, for example: 28/11/2024 is > 01/12/2024 stringwise

We don't have the example data for tables like cs_facilities, cs_fundingMethods, ci_periodicBillings etc.
I created this example based on the sample data you provided and the expectation that you shared.
Fiddle
WITH RateChanges AS (
    SELECT 
        Client,
        Rate,
        Funding,
        LastUpdated,
        LAG(Rate) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) AS PreviousRate,
        LAG(Funding) OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY LastUpdated DESC) AS PreviousFunding
    FROM ClientBillingInfo
    WHERE LastUpdated BETWEEN '2024-09-01' AND '2024-09-30'  -- Filtering only September 2024
)
SELECT 
    Client,
    Rate AS LatestRate,
    PreviousRate,
    Funding AS LatestFunding,
    PreviousFunding,
    LastUpdated
FROM RateChanges
WHERE PreviousRate IS NOT NULL  -- Ensures that there's a previous rate (indicating a change)
ORDER BY Client, LastUpdated DESC;

Output:

